# twitter-bootstrap typeahead ajax TypeError

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this code:

```
    $('.ajax-typeahead').typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: $(this)[0].$element.data('link'),
            type: 'get',
            data: {q: query},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res) {
                return  process(res);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and when I type something in the input field I'm getting:

> bootstrap.min.js (line 1)
>
> TypeError: a is undefined

Does anyone know when went wrong?

EDIT: I updated to latest version 2.3 and now everything works!

Answer (score 0):

I updated to latest version 2.3 and now everything works!

Comment: Is there a way I can see your full code? I've been trying to get this to work for weeks now and still now luck!